# VBA array of unique values is not picking up certain numbers

Tags: vba, excel

I have written some code that scans a list of numbers and stores the unique values in an array. The numbers range from 1 to 12 (they represent months and are ordered sequentially) and look like this:

**A**|
 10
 10
 10
 11
 11
12
12
12
12
1
1
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
4
5
5
etc.

The numbers are in column I, from row 2 to the last row of each sheet. The issue I am running into is that the numbers 1 and 2 are not stored in the array. When the below code is run on my spreadsheet, the array stored as:

10 | 11 | 12 | 3 | 4 | 5  etc. (if there are more months)

I am not sure why this is happening - I suspect that its because the month immediately preceding 1 and 2 is 12, which contains the digits 1 and 2. However, I am not sure why the code would skip that, or how to fix it. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

```
Dim i as integer
Dim tmp as string, msg as string, arr as string
Dim ws as worksheet
Dim lastrow as long

Set ws = ActiveSheet
lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For Each cell In ws.Range("I2:I" & lastrow)
        If (cell <> "") And (InStr(tmp, cell) = 0) Then
            tmp = tmp & cell & "|"
        End If
    Next cell

If Len(tmp) > 0 Then tmp = Left(tmp, Len(tmp) - 1)
    arr = Split(tmp, "|")
        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            msg = msg & arr(i) & vbNewLine
        Next i
```

Comment: `arr` isn't declared as an array. It's declared as a `String`. This code won't even compile.

Comment: See how to create a [mcve].  (Note the "verifiable" part.)

Comment: instr (12,1) = 1. So your code has an error.
It is a good idea to use the dictionary object to get a unique number.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess your problem is (as mentioned in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52638273/vba-array-of-unique-values-is-not-picking-up-certain-numbers/52639174#comment92209727_52638273)) because you're building up a string which looks like this:

```
10 | 11 | 12
```

but when testing the string you are using:

```
InStr(tmp, cell) = 0
```

If the `cell` contains `1`, then `InStr(tmp, cell)` will not return `0`, because the `1` is already in the built-up string (as part of `10`, `11`, or `12`).

You could fix this by building up the string as follows:

```
|10|11|12|
```

and then checking:

```
InStr(tmp, "|" & cell & "|") = 0
```

`InStr` will only match the cell value when it is surrounded by pipe characters (`|`).

---

However, I think a far simpler solution would be to use a `Scripting.Dictionary` to build a list of the unique numbers:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim cell As Variant

' Add a reference (Tools -> References...) to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Dim dict as New Scripting.Dictionary

Set ws = ActiveSheet
lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For Each cell In ws.Range("I2:I" & lastrow)
    If cell.Value <> "" Then
        dict(cell.Value) = 1 ' dummy value; we're only interested in the dictionary keys
    End If
Next cell
```

and then use the `Join` function together with the dictionary's `Keys` collection to build a string of the delimited values:

```
Dim msg As String
msg = Join(dict.Keys, vbNewLine)
```

This works because the dictionary only keeps a single key/value entry for a given key.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim tmp As String, msg As String, arr As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim dic As Object
    Dim s As String
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        For Each cell In ws.Range("I2:I" & lastrow)
            'If (cell <> "") And (InStr(tmp, cell) = 0) Then
            If cell <> "" Then
                s = CStr(cell)
                If dic.Exists(s) Then
                Else
                    dic.Add s, s
                    tmp = tmp & cell & "|"
                End If
            End If
        Next cell

    If Len(tmp) > 0 Then tmp = Left(tmp, Len(tmp) - 1)
        arr = Split(tmp, "|")
            For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
                msg = msg & arr(i) & vbNewLine
            Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Since your `If` block is empty, I would switch the logic: `If Not dic.Exists ...`. Also since the dictionary will keep only unique values in its set of keys, why do you have to add the value only if it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

Or like this if you want to use an array and not a dictionary object ...

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Process()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim msg As String
    Dim arr() As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim cell As Variant
    Dim FoundAt As Long

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    lastrow = ws.Cells(1048576, "I").End(xlUp).Row

    For Each cell In ws.Range("I2:I" & lastrow)
        If (cell <> "") Then

            FoundAt = -1
            If Len(Join(arr)) > 0 Then
                For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
                    If arr(i) = cell Then FoundAt = i
                Next
            End If

            If FoundAt = -1 Then
                If Len(Join(arr)) > 0 Then
                    ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) + 1)
                Else
                    ReDim arr(1)
                End If
                arr(UBound(arr)) = cell
            End If

        End If
    Next cell

    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        msg = msg & arr(i) + vbCrLf
    Next

    MsgBox msg

End Sub
```

[image]